# removing black border around user icon blue coloring

Tags: image, paint

I have these images that I've colored blue, but they have a black outline around the images. Can anyone tell me how I can remove the black outline in MS paint? Or another tool that is easy to use and free?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [miniPaint](https://viliusle.github.io/miniPaint/). It's a online site.

Use Tool->Replace Color and replace Black with Transparent and Power ~25 like so:

[image]

The final result is quite good i think

[image]

**Note** slide Alpha to 0 in order to replace with Transparent color